# React app Jest unit test failing with Microsoft application insights react plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to use the Microsoft's Application Insights JavaScript SDK React Plugin in my React application, and although it's working successfully, I'm having trouble getting my Jest and Enzyme unit test to pass with it.

I've set up my unit test like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../App.view';

jest.mock('@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js', () => ({
  ReactPlugin: Object,
}));

jest.mock('@microsoft/applicationinsights-web', () => ({
  ApplicationInsights: Object,
  loadAppInsights: () => ({}),
}));

describe('App View', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    act(() => {
      ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
    });
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });
});
```

With my application insights service as:

```
import {ApplicationInsights} from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import {ReactPlugin, withAITracking} from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

// Set up AppInsights connection
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory({basename: ''});
const reactPlugin = new ReactPlugin();
const ai = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    instrumentationKey:
      process.env.REACT_APP_APPINSIGHTS_KEY || 'xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx',
    extensions: [reactPlugin],
    extensionConfig: {
      [reactPlugin.identifier]: {history: browserHistory},
    },
  },
});
ai.loadAppInsights();

export default Component => withAITracking(reactPlugin, Component);
export const appInsights = ai.appInsights;
```

When I run my tests, I keep getting the error, `TypeError: ai.loadAppInsights is not a function`

Since I'm using jest mocking for the application insights modules, I've tried to mock this method as well in several ways, but with no luck. Any ideas on what I'm missing here? I'm also unable to find any good documentation on how to properly integrate application insights into a React application, which includes proper unit testing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this mock and it is working,

```
jest.mock('@microsoft/applicationinsights-web', () => ({
  ApplicationInsights: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    loadAppInsights: jest.fn(),
    addTelemetryInitializer: jest.fn(),
    trackPageView: jest.fn(),
    trackException: jest.fn(),
    trackTrace: jest.fn(),
    trackEvent: jest.fn(),
    flush: jest.fn(),
    startTrackPage: jest.fn(),
    stopTrackPage: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```